# Relative Layout, Textview not showing

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I am using this XML to show my one `Button` at the bottom and one `TextView` at the top with one `TextView` right in the middle. The middle textview covers the whole span in between the button and the top textview. The middle `TextView` is not being displayed at all. What is wrong?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/task"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="@string/tasks"
        />
    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/btnAddTask"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="@string/AddTasks"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
        />
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/TasksList"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="@string/tasks" 
        android:layout_above="@id/task"
        android:layout_below="@id/btnAddTask"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: +1 For showing the whole code in code tags without bothering the moderators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is definitely that you have the TasksList TextView below your button. Swap your layout_above and layout_below values. This works for me:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/task"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="@string/tasks"
        />
    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/btnAddTask"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="@string/AddTasks"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
        />
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/TasksList"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="@string/tasks" 
        android:layout_above="@id/btnAddTask"
        android:layout_below="@id/task"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

There's definitely something wrong with how you have this laid out.

You have for the button, `alignParentBottom="true"`... then for the TasksList `TextView` it is set to be below the button... basically off the screen.

You can remove orientation from the `RelativeLayout`... Relative layout's do not have orientation like LinearLayout's do.

As you're describing... I'm not 100% you can do it with a `Relative Layout`. If you simply wanted one thing on top, one centered and the other on bottom, it would be best to use a single layout parameter for each one, `centerInParent`, `alignParentTop` and `alignParentBottom`.

If you reconsider `LinearLayout` (as I'm guessing you started with) you'd stick with a Vertical Orientation, then give them `layout_weight` of 0, 1, and 0 making sure the height was set to wrap_content.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/task"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_weight="0" 
        />
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/TasksList"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="@string/tasks" 
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        />
    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/btnAddTask"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="@string/AddTasks"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem wsa that you reversed your layout above and the layout below:
try

```
android:layout_below="@id/task"
android:layout_above="@id/btnAddTask"
```

See screenshot.

And here is the complete layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/task"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="@string/tasks"
        />
    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/btnAddTask"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="@string/AddTasks"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
        />
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/TasksList"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="@string/tasks" 
        android:layout_below="@id/task"
        android:layout_above="@id/btnAddTask"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: That wouldn't be what the OP is asking for... there's supposed to be 3 views... 2 TextViews and 1 Button.

Comment: I think that top one with the grey is the Activity title... not one of the views from this layout...

Comment: OK you're right. I was not paying enough attention. I posted a correction above, and a new screen grab.